# ASP.NET Core with Docker support: Connection refused

Tags: asp.net, .net, oracle, docker

I have a ASP .NET Core (v2.0) app with Docker support.
And I want to start a Oracle Database when starting my app.
This is how my docker-compose file looks like:

```
version: '3'

services:
  devarttestapp:
    image: devarttestapp
    build:
      context: ./DevartTestApp
      dockerfile: Dockerfile

  oracledb:
    image: sath89/oracle-12c
    ports: 
      - "1521:1521"
```

I use Devart data provider dotConnect for Oracle.

```
var conn = new Devart.Data.Oracle.OracleConnection();
conn.ConnectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ORACLE_CONNECTION_STRING");
try
{
    conn.Open();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e);
    throw;
}
```

But when I try to connect to the database of the created Oracle DB container I get following exception:

System.Net.Internals.SocketExceptionFactory+ExtendedSocketException (Connection refused 127.0.0.1:1521)

I also tried to include the depends_on as well as the networks option in my docker-compose file with the same results.

What could be the cause of this exception?
And how do I solve this problem?

Comment: please check if it helps http://www.oracledebugging.com/2011/09/oracle-database-10g-debugging.html

Comment: http://www.oracledebugging.com/2011/09/oracle-database-10g-debugging_16.html

Comment: The database is not the problem since I can connect to it. Only the web app running in a Docker container seems to have problems to connect to the database in the other Docker container.

Comment: check the client trace to identify the problem

Answer (score 1):

From within the container, can you send me the output of this command?

`apt-get update && apt-get install nmap -y && nmap -p 1521 localhost`

If you are unfamiliar with how to access bash inside the container, this is how:

Find your container ID or name: `docker ps`
Connect to BASH: `docker exec -it >containerID< /bin/bash`

I have a feeling that his issue pertains to Oracle rather than Docker as your docker-compose file looks correct. Perhaps the listener hasn't been enabled. I would also appreciate the output of: `lsnrctl status` if `nmap` says that the port is not `open`.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e41945/listenercfg.htm#NETAG010

Comment: This is the output: Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.00015s latency).
Other addresses for localhost (not scanned): 127.0.0.1
PORT     STATE SERVICE
1521/tcp open  oracle

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.36 seconds

Comment: This is the output for lsnrctl status: LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production on 16-AUG-2017 19:09:32

Connecting to (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=)(PORT=1521))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
Start Date                16-AUG-2017 19:04:26
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 5 min. 6 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF

Comment: Part 2: Listener Log File         /u01/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/6d592052063a/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=6d592052063a)(PORT=1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=6d592052063a)(PORT=8080))(Presentation=HTTP)(Session=RAW))
Services Summary...
Service "xe.oracle.docker" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "xe", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "xeXDB.oracle.docker" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "xe", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully

Comment: Okay, Oracle is running properly and the service is port forwarded. I suspect that you are not connecting to the database correctly.

This error message `System.Net.Internals.SocketExceptionFactory+ExtendedSocketException (Connection refused 127.0.0.1:1521)` implies that you attempted to connect to an Oracle database running on localhost (127.0.0.1). Was this error message generated from within the container? if you are trying to access a database running in a container from outside the container and you receive that error then you are targeting your machine not the container.

Comment: Can you attempt to connect to the Oracle database from within the container using `sqlplus`? I think you simply execute `sqlplus / as sysdba` from the user account that the database is running on. (Unless the SID is exported globally in an environment variable)

Also, please share all future code and log snippets using an external platform like GitHub Gist for readability. These comments are an eyestrain.

Comment: Yes. I can connect using sqlplus from within the container

Comment: Please see the comment immediately before the one pertaining to `sqlplus`.  The error message you're receiving implies you're connecting to the database via `localhost`. Which doesn't make sense unless that was initiated from within the Docker container.

Comment: I disagree. When I try to connect to the database outside the container on the host (for example via SQL Developer) to the same address (LOCALHOST:1521) it works. Only the ASP .NET Core application running in another container seems to have problems.

Comment: Part 1)

Sorry, I think I misunderstood your issue until now.

The reason that your host can connect to the container is because the port is exposed to the host. However, individual containers will not network OOB.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/container-communication/#container-communication-between-hosts

>For security reasons, Docker configures the iptables rules to prevent containers from forwarding traffic from outside the host machine, on Linux hosts. Docker sets the default policy of the FORWARD chain to DROP.

Comment: Part 2) Here is information on how to configure docker containers to communicate via DNS, namely initiate your container with --hostname and make sure the firewall is configured to allow inter-container communication and you should be good to go. To test, simply `nmap -p 1521 >othercontainer<`

https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/configure-dns/

Comment: Thank you. How can I adjust my docker-compose file to make it work? If you adjust your answer respectively I can accept it.

Comment: I tried to change the host address of the db connection string from LOCALHOST to ORACLEDB. But now I get the error: No such device or address

Comment: Hi, I just realized I never circled back to you on this issue. Have you now solved it? Sorry about that.

Comment: Thanks. I think I upgraded Docker, ASP.NET Core to newer versions and then it worked...

Answer (score 0):

I faced with the same problem on my mac. I solved it using port that > 9000.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `SslMode=None;` in your connection string

```
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=db-host; Database=db-name; Uid=db-user; Pwd=db-pwd; SslMode=None;"
  },
```